# Can naming/running a program “sudo” somehow cause problems?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, data-recovery, sudo

I hope this is an appropriate place to post this--I have no idea what happened.

I named a c++ file (a simple sudoku solver) "sudo.cpp" and then compiled it with "g++ sudo.cpp -o sudo" and ran "./sudo" from my directory /Code using Terminal. For some reason, moments after, Terminal froze, outputted strange text (I didn't have time to read it), and the computer crashed. Now I cannot boot (I get the blinking folder) and the hard drive does not even show up in Disk Utility when I start in Recovery Mode. Is there any way that the sudo command and the name of a file can conflict and somehow cause problems? I know it is a long-shot, but I can't imagine why a simple sudoku solver would otherwise (apparently) erase my hard-drive, and it seems very unlikely to be a coincidence.

(I was working on a MacBook Pro Mid-2014, 16 GB RAM, 512 GB Memory.)

Comment: I think this was just an uncanny coincidence. The only real explanation seems to be hardware related. It just happened at a bizarre time, and I was wrapped up in the idea that there was a potential naming conflict.

Comment: Thats strange and I never heard before whether anyone named a application "sudo". For that reason I have only one solution you should reinstall mac os. If you have a backup (for example Time Machine) you can boot into Internet Recovery (press at startup CMD + R + i) and restore from Time Machine. Otherwise make a backup and make a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo` already exists, and runs what comes next as a superuser (usually after requesting a password). Then you can, for instance, delete all sorts if system files.

No idea what actually happened, but some conflict seems possible. It seems like a really bad idea to name your game after such a powerful command!